# If the Democrats get rid of the filibuster to pass voting rights can the next congress repeal these voting rights with a simple majority?

Tags: united-states, voting, senate, civil-rights, filibuster

If the Democrats get rid of the filibuster to pass voting rights can the next congress repeal these voting rights with a simple majority?

[Targeting State Restrictions, House Passes Landmark Voting Rights Expansion](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/03/us/politics/house-voting-rights-bill.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> If the Democrats get rid of the filibuster to pass voting rights can the next congress repeal these voting rights with a simple majority?

The next Congress? Probably not. The next Congress runs from January 2023 to January 2025, during which Biden will still be President. Even assuming the Republicans win both houses of the legislature, they'll need to have a 2/3 majority in both houses to override a presidential veto. That would require that the Republicans win a net of seventeen seats in the 2022 senatorial elections.

Given that Democrats currently hold only 14 of the 34 Senate seats that will be contested in the 2022 elections, and given that 10 of those 14 seats are very safe seats, the likelihood that Republicans will achieve a veto-proof majority in the Senate in the next Congress is essentially impossible.

Comment: To whomever tried to change my use of "senatorial elections" to "congressional elections", I meant what I wrote. While the term "congressional elections" sometimes is used to describe elections for both the House of Representatives and the Senate, it is typically used to describe only the elections for the House of Representatives. As there is no filibuster rule in the House of Representatives, the only elections of concern are those for the US Senate.

Comment: I find myself wondering what insidious nonsense they could do with a bare majority that wouldn't repeal it outright but damage it to the point where enforcement fails.

Comment: Right. The only way this works out is if they get a majority in both Houses and win the Presidency. Plus several Republicans have stated that, if the law passes, they will no longer be able to win and thus will not win a majority.

Comment: @Joshua: Very little. About all they can do is tie it to some important piece of legislation, like the budget or NDAA, and then force Biden to veto it. This could result in a government shutdown (remember those?), but there is simply no provision under the US Constitution for Congress to enact anything without either a presidential signature or a veto override (or, rarely, the president ignoring the bill, which makes it become law automatically after ten days, Sundays excepted).

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly useful to focus so heavily on the very next Congress rather than just addressing what any future Congress can do. It seems quite unlikely that the asker cares specifically about the 2023 Congress specifically as opposed to the next Congress where Republicans have majority decision-making power. Even if they did care specifically about the former, the latter makes for a much more useful answer (and nothing stops an answer from addressing both) that would address the obvious variants like "what about the 2025 Congress" or what if this happens a few years from now.

Comment: @Kevin: I do not want to speak of any specific ideas because somebody might actually try them; but it is plausible to my mind they could set off a spark that would undermine it so greatly in people's minds that enforcing it would result in the law fracturing on appellate court jurisdictions. There are tools that have never been used.

Comment: @Joshua: They have hundreds of people whose whole job is to think of these things and try to implement them. If you can think of it, I guarantee that someone else has already considered it and rated it on a scale from "impossible" to "let's try it next week."

Comment: @Kevin: I saw on the news that 45 states were attempting various laws aimed at voter suppression. Assuming that wasn't a typo in the news headline, at that level of strength the normal calculus is wrong and invoking the Tenth Amendment which has long been toothless is likely to work.

Comment: Here's a case far removed from modern politics https://scholarship.law.ufl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1026&context=flr

Comment: Seems like it would be worth adding that the first congress under the next Republican POTUS certainly could (and likely would) do just that though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they can because that is how congress works, any bill passed by a simple majority can be repealed by a simple majority.

All bills can be passed with a simple majority, the filibuster has nothing to do with passing a bill. It is just a procedure that is designed to hold up the vote on a bill by using debate. The problem is with the modern filibuster there is no actual debate that is happening.

If the filibuster was working as designed senators would be debating on the floor until the filibuster is resolved and this would prevent other work from happening during this time. The filibuster is intended to be disruptive to the work in the senate and not be a simple way to stop a vote from happening. It used to be that the only way to filibuster a bill in the senate was to stand on the floor and speak for the entire time but at one point they decided that was keeping other work from happening so they changed it to just threaten use of it. Now the filibuster doesn't prevent work from happening but it makes it trivial to filibuster a bill with no consequences or intention to work on a solution and bring the bill up for a vote.

Comment: Any law can be repealed by a simple majority regardless of how it was passed, but only if the president agrees.  If the president does not agree, a 2/3 supermajority is necessary.

Comment: @phoog That is correct but that is not what this question is asking about. It is asking about what congress passing a law not about the law getting signed or needing to override a veto as those two items are unrelated to the filibuster.

Comment: I understand.  I'm just saying that the first sentence implies a condition that does not exist.  Perhaps "any law can be repealed through the normal lawmaking process" or something like that.  (Also, as this is [Politics.SE], it might be worth mentioning that the constitutionally possible is frequently constrained by the politically possible.)

Comment: @phoog I think you are being overly picky here as this question is about congress passing a bill not about a president signing it or vetoing it.

Comment: @phoog The 2/3 point is great and provides another mandatory detail of what is required to repeal a law. In theory if the Democrats pass a law ensuring voting rights the supreme court may block a law that has abolishing voting rights as its sole purpose. If they increase voting rights in such a way that greatly increases the integrity of the election process then Republicans cannot use this as an excuse to rescind voting rights.

Comment: @polcott if a state law is in conflict with federal law then _any_ court can block the state law.  It's usually not necessary for the supreme court to get involved unless lower courts disagree or make a serious error on some question of law.  But the reality is far more complicated. No law would ever claim its purpose is to abolish voting rights, for example.  Joe W: perhaps I am being overly picky, but the fact is that congress passing a bill by simple majority is not sufficient for that bill to become law. Many people are aware of that, but not all, so it's better not to gloss over it.

Comment: @phoog Without the filibuster or a presidential veto it looks like a simple majority is enough to pass a law, likewise the same thing for a later repeal of this same law. If the voting rights act made sure to add provisions making voting integrity much stronger the Republicans lose that as an excuse for repealing the law.

Comment: The filibuster was never *intended* to be anything; it basically happened by accident, and then senators from the South started using it to block legislation they disliked (notably civil rights legislation). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filibuster_in_the_United_States_Senate  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strom_Thurmond_filibuster_of_the_Civil_Rights_Act_of_1957

Comment: @PaulJohnson That is a good history of it.

Comment: @polcott but they don't lose the argument that it's unconstitutional.  The Constitution explicitly says states get to decide how their elections work.

Comment: @Ryan_L The Times, Places and Manner of holding Elections for Senators and Representatives, shall be prescribed in each State by the Legislature thereof; but the Congress may at any time by Law make or alter such Regulations, except as to the Places of chusing Senators.   https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI_S4_C1_1_1_1_1/

Comment: @Ryan_L https://www.everycrsreport.com/reports/RL30747.html 

https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/interpretation/article-i/clauses/750

Comment: @JoeW If Congress passes a bill to repeal but POTUS vetoes it, the law hasn't actually been repealed. Congress took a vote but it had no effect.

Comment: @Barmar That is correct but this is asking about the filibuster in the senate which is something that they have to get past before it can even get the the presidents desk to be signed or vetoed.  If this question is about a veto than they would need 2/3rds majority to override the veto which is also more than enough to kill a filibuster.

Comment: @JoeW I think the point is that it matters whether the President is on the side that would use the filibuster or opposing it. With POTUS in favor of voting rights, if they eliminate the filibuster it can be passed into law, and the next Congress can't repeal it because they won't be able to get a veto-proof majority.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear whether this question is asking a technical constitutional question or a practical question. Theoretically they could repeal it if they could get enough Democrats to switch positions, but that's practically impossible.

Comment: @Barmar The question appears to be asking if congress could pass something or not as in the end all the filibuster does is prevent something from coming up for a vote. Even if it gets past the filibuster it doesn't mean it is going to get passed in the senate as people can vote to end the filibuster with the intent of voting against the bill.

Comment: @JoeW That's technically how the filibuster is defined, but it's not how it works in practice. If the minority party threatens a filibuster and there aren't 60 votes for the resolution, it's effectively DOA.

Comment: @Barmar It still ends up being the same where a bill can't get to a vote unless it gets 60 votes and even if it does it doesn't mean it will pass. That is also why there is a push to git rid or or make people actually debate for a filibuster again.

Answer (score 3):

**Including the prior provided answer along with key commentary on this answer:** 
It looks like the Democrats can get rid of the filibuster to pass voting rights. The next congress could repeal this law with a simple majority unless there is a presidential veto. This seems to indicate that voting rights would last at least until the next presidential election.

If the next president is Republican (not as likely with much stronger voting rights) and the congress has a Republican majority of both houses then (in theory) the voting rights could be repealed. **If these voting rights are accompanied by much stronger measures to ensure voting integrity then the supreme court may over-rule any repeal that only seeks to eliminate voting rights.**

Comment: "not as likely with much stronger voting rights" => source?

Comment: I am the source of that. I thought all these things though before I asked my question. It turns out that the new bill implements several of the ideas that I thought of before I ever looked at the bill. The other key idea that must also be implemented is a way to make the voting process airtight. If that is part of the bill there there is no excuse what-so-ever to repeal it.

Answer (score 3):

What is legally possible is irrelevant. Once the filibuster is removed there is no likelihood of a subsequent Senate, either Democrat or Republican trying to reinstate it.

In 2013 the Demcrats removed the filibuster for Judicial appointments below the Supreme Court and Republicans objected. After becoming that majority party in 2016 no move to restore this filibuster was made and the Republican Majority the decided to go further and remove the filibuster for Supreme Court appointments as well. There has been no hint of the 2020 Senate looking to put either of these filibusters back.

Republicans will not restore the legislative filibuster if it is removed.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes, if Republicans win a simple majority in both Houses of Congress as well as the presidency, they could then repeal this law with a simple majority. A repeal is just another law that says the previous law is no longer valid, and so the rules would be the same for it as for any other law.

However, there is a wrinkle. The purpose of the voting rights bill is to try and make voting more fair by preventing any limitations on voting and preventing gerrymandering, tactics that Republicans are purportedly using (e.g. [laws passed in Georgia recently](https://www.cnn.com/2021/03/26/politics/georgia-voting-law-black-voters/index.html)). These attempts are suggested to be because Republicans feel they need them to be able to win. As such, it is widely thought that a bill forbidding them would make it harder harder for Republicans to win without changing their policies.

This isn't just something Democrats are saying. Republican Senator Ted Cruz, in his opposition to the For the People Act, has stated "[H.R. 1′s only objective is to ensure that Democrats can never again lose another election, that they will win and maintain control of the House of Representatives and the Senate and of the state legislatures for the next century](https://apnews.com/article/legislature-voting-rights-ted-cruz-legislation-elections-6270306f67108ac16f4ee7b45a8afdb3)."

This is a large part of the political calculations for this move---whether or not the Republicans would be able to easily undo legislation Democrats pass after the removal or nerfing of the procedural filibuster. Without a bill like HR1 or general sentiment that Republicans are limiting voting to try and win elections, such a move would be less politically viable.